# Use Doctrine to merge entity with different subclass

Tags: symfony, inheritance, doctrine-orm, merge, doctrine

I have a mapped superclass `AbstractQuestion` with single-table-inheritance.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\MappedSuperclass
 * @ORM\Table(name="Question")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="dtype", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({
 *  "simple":   "SimpleQuestion",
 *  "dropdown": "DropdownQuestion"
 * })
 */
abstract class AbstractQuestion
```

`SimpleQuestion` and `DropdownQuestion` inherit from this superclass.

```
/**
 * Class SimpleQuestion.
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class SimpleQuestion extends AbstractQuestion
```

I want to modify an existing `SimpleQuestion` and make it a `DropdownQuestion`.

When saving a question, I deserialise and merge the question, which contains an ID and the 'dtype' and other properties.

```
$dquestion = $this->serial->fromJson($request->getContent(), AbstractQuestion::class);
$question = $this->em->merge($dquestion);
$this->em->flush();
```

So I submit something like:

```
{ id: 12, dtype: 'dropdown', 'text': 'What is my favourite animal?'}
```

After the deserialisation, `$dquestion` is a `DropdownQuestion` object as I desired, but after the merge `$question` is a `SimpleQuestion` object as it was in the database previously, so any unique properties of DropdownQuestion are lost and the question is saved as a SimpleQuestion. Is there any way to work around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will first have to delete the existing record (`SimpleQuestion`) and then insert the new record (`DropdownQuestion`). Type casting is not supported in Doctrine 2.

---

**Note.**
You can probably change the discriminator column with a pure SQL query, but this [is absolutely not recommended and will for sure give you problems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12613418/1697459)...

Check also the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5938418/how-to-change-and-entity-type-in-doctrine2-cti-inheritance) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6263332/how-to-convert-entity-leaving-it-id) since they might be interesting for you.

Comment: Thanks. Disappointing, but true. I ended up in this situation because I converted a serialized object stored in a long text into an entity. Otherwise I guess I wouldn't have considered changing the question type. Thanks.